# Customized sort in Typescript

Tags: typescript, sorting

Say I have array

```
products= [{
"Name":'xyz',
'ID': 1
},
{
"Name":'abc',
'ID': 5
},
{
"Name":'def',
'ID': 3
}
]

sortOrder=[3,1,5]
```

if I do,

```
sortOrder.forEach((item) => {
        products.sort((productA) => {
          if (productA.ID=== item) { return 1; } else { return -1; }
        });
      });
```

It's not sorting as per order specified in sortOrder. I want to to sort products array based sortOrder mentioned in sortOrder array. so, output of above should be , `{ "Name":'def', 'ID': 3 },{ "Name":'xyz', 'ID': 1 },{ "Name":'abc', 'ID': 5 }`

Any suggestion?

Comment: This code tells it to (1) sort the list putting the 3s at the end, then (2) sort the list putting the 1s at the end, then (3) sort the list putting the 5s at the end.  Is that what you intended?  What were you trying to do / what was your expected output?

Comment: Basically I want to to sort products array based sortOrder mentioned in sortOrder array. so, o/p of above should be , {
"Name":'def',
'ID': 3
},{
"Name":'xyz',
'ID': 1
},{
"Name":'abc',
'ID': 5
}

Comment: First of all sorting is not exclusive for ts, following  is the link for official documentation of soring by mozilla, [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer to account for duplicate values in products list.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  products= [{
"Name":'xyz',
'ID': 1
},
{
"Name":'abc',
'ID': 5
},
{
"Name":'def',
'ID': 3
},{
"Name":'xyz',
'ID': 1
},
{
"Name":'abc',
'ID': 5
},
{
"Name":'def',
'ID': 3
},
{
"Name":'def',
'ID': 3
},
{
"Name":'def',
'ID': 3
}
]

sortOrder=[3,1,5];

sortProducts(){
  var tempSortedProducts :any[]=[];

  for(let idx=0; idx<this.sortOrder.length; idx++){

      this.products.forEach((product)=>{
        if(product.ID===this.sortOrder[idx]){
            tempSortedProducts.push(product)
        } 
      })
  }
  this.products = tempSortedProducts;
}
}
```

Stackbliz link: [Custom Sort](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohtzaa)

Comment: This gives issue when when you have 2 records with same ID. It only considers only last one. So result of this would may have less than items than original

Comment: @Kedar, I specifically pointed out that I assume we are dealing with unique IDs.  Do your products have duplicate ID's?  or your sort order? or both?

Comment: Correct. Duplicate Ids can be in Products but not in sortOrder

Comment: @Kedar, I've update the answer this should work.  I'm not sure that it is the most efficient way to do it -but it gets you what you want.